# Different results when subtracting two timestamps using AGE (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

Can anyone help me to understand why these are showing different outputs?

```
SELECT 
EXTRACT (epoch FROM ('2021-02-01 00:00:00'::timestamp - '2021-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp)) / 3600 / 24 as time1,
EXTRACT (epoch FROM age('2021-02-01 00:00:00'::timestamp , '2021-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp)) / 3600 / 24 as time2
```

output:

| time1 | time2 |
| --- | --- |
| 31 | 30 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the subtract operator and the function `age(),` per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html):

> timestamp - timestamp › interval
>
> Subtract timestamps (converting 24-hour intervals into days, similarly to justify_hours())

versus

> age ( timestamp, timestamp ) › interval
>
> Subtract arguments, producing a “symbolic” result that uses years and months, rather than just days

Example:

```sql
SELECT 
    '2021-02-01 00:00:00'::timestamp - '2021-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp as interval1,
    age('2021-02-01 00:00:00'::timestamp , '2021-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp) as interval2
    
 interval1 | interval2
-----------+-----------
 31 days   | 1 mon
(1 row)
```

The second interval is converted to 30 days in the further calculations described in the question.